# how to pass a reference to const pointer correctly?

Tags: visual-c++

I just wonder how I can efficiently pass a reference to const pointer to an object of a class.
For example,

```
class BigData
{
public:
   int m[1000];
};

void Func(const BigData* const& bigData)
{
// just read bigData; No modification on bigData.
}

int main()
{
  BigData* bigData = new BigData();
  Func(bigData);
}
```

Above example, I do not quite understand why I have to put const before reference(&).
If I try to build it without the reference, the compiler complains about 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BigData *' to 'const BigData *&'

Seems like it is related to R-value rule but I don't know what rule exactly governs this case.

TIA

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't.  Just pass the pointer by value.  Syntactically it is easier for the called function to use, and will have less overhead.

```
void Func(const BigData *bigData)
```